# Flash Builder 4.6 scrollToIndex not working for me

Tags: list, flash-builder

I need to be able to select an index and have it visible. I can get the index to be selected but can't get it to scroll...

```
    for (var _index:int=0; _index < registrarsAll.length; _index++) {
        registrarsList.addItemAt(registrarsAll[_index].name, registrarsList.length);
        registrarsIDs.addItemAt(registrarsAll[_index].id, registrarsIDs.length)

        if(registrarsAll[_index].id == judgeID) {
            judgesLB.selectedIndex = registrarsIDs.length-1;    
        }   
    }

    judgesLB.scrollToIndex(judgesLB.selectedIndex);
```

The index gets selected but I can't get it to scroll into view. I am calling this on creationComplete. registrarsList is the data source for the list judgesLB.

thanks for any help.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work in the updateComplete event of the judgesLB list...

```
updateComplete = "{((judgesLB.selectedIndex>13)?judgesLB.scrollToIndex(judgesLB.selectedIndex):null)}"
```

selectedIndex cannot be negative. -1 will generate an error.